# Cordova plugins do not work on ios emulator

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm developing an application with Cordova. When texting the application plugins work only on android device and not on the ios emulator.

Test android device:

```
cordova run android
```

Test ios:

i use the Xcode and run in ios emulator

The plugins are: Cordova Device an Cordova Battery Status.

Can Device and Status objects only work on device?

thanks Ciao!

Comment: how exactly they don't work? do you get any error messages in the log?

Comment: Do you tried to remove and re-add these plugins ?

Comment: I tried with a simple example of Cordova Docs :window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);

        function onBatteryStatus(status) 
        {
            alert("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
        }